# (Non) Associativity of Exterior Product on Modules of $\text{dim} \geq 2$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules, exterior-algebra

Associativity probably isn't the right word here, but close enough.

Suppose $M$ is a vector space over a field. Suppose $2 \leq \text{dim}(M) \leq \infty$. Suppose $N = \bigwedge^2 M$.

Then I want to see when$\bigwedge^2N \not \cong \bigwedge^4 M$, i.e, $\bigwedge^2(\bigwedge^2M) \not \cong \bigwedge^4 M$, and when $\bigwedge^2 N \cong \bigwedge^4 M$.

Observation: When $2 \leq \text{dim}(M) < \infty$, we have that $\bigwedge^2 N \not \cong \bigwedge^4 M$. This comes from observing the dimensions of the two:

Suppose $\text{dim}(M) = k$. Then if $\{e_1, \cdots, e_k\}$ is the basis for $M$. Then I believe that $\{(e_i, e_j) : 1 \leq i < j \leq k\}$ and $\{(e_i, e_j, e_l, e_m) : 1 \leq i < j < l < m \leq k\}$ is the bases for $\bigwedge^2M$ and $\bigwedge^4 M$ respectively.

Using this idea then: one should come to the conclusion that $\text{dim}(\bigwedge^2N) = {\text{dim}N \choose 2} = {{k \choose 2} \choose 2}$ and $\text{dim}(\bigwedge^4M) = {k \choose 4}$.

From here I believe it's easy enough to show that ${{k \choose 2} \choose 2} > {k \choose 4}$ (for $k \geq 2$) and we're done. $\square$

Question: What about when $\text{dim}(M) = \infty$, i.e, when it's countably infinite. It's unclear to me what happens here- the dimensions match up I believe (you just get $\infty$ for both $\bigwedge^2 N$ and $\bigwedge^4 M$). So is it $\bigwedge^2 N \cong \bigwedge^4 M$? How does one make the bijections between the bases? Do we just say that the cardinality of both bases is $\aleph_0$? How do we show that the bases have this cardinality? I was thinking of some sort of injection like: $(e_i, e_j) \mapsto (e_{2^i3^j})$ and similarly $(e_i, e_j, e_l, e_m) \mapsto (e_{2^i3^j5^l7^m})$? But all of a sudden this has turned into a set theory question which is weird to me. I was wondering if there was a more standard way to prove this?

Comment: It becomes pure set theory, right. As vector spaces, they will be all isomorphic to each other because they have the same infinite dimension.

Comment: Yeah I figured. Also- it just occured to me that if $\text{dim} = 2$, then $\bigwedge^4 M = 0$ and then $\text{dim} N  = 1$ and thus $\bigwedge^2 N = 0$ and thus in this case we *do* have $\bigwedge^2 N \cong \bigwedge^4 M$, correct? This seems right to me but I was told that this is not true even when $n = 2$.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.

Comment: @NuanceIsDead Given that you're only interested in the cardinalities of the two spaces, it may be misleading to express that equality as $\cong$. (To me the question initially read as though you were looking for an algebra automorphism, i.e., a bijection that preserves the wedge products.)